# Как записать два списка в один?

Tags: c#

У меня есть 3 списка, к примеру ( корзина, белые яблоки и красные яблоки) , Могу ли я записать 2 списка (белых и красных яблок ) в одну "корзину". 
//
Просто я хочу , потом перебирать эту корзину яблок и сверять к какому списку он раньше относился

```
public class White : IApple
{
    int IApple.Age { get; set; }

    public White()
    {
       int quantityWhite=2;

        List<White> white = new List<White>();
        for (int i = 0; i < quantityWhite ; i++) { white.Add(new White()); }
     }
}

public class Red : IApple
{       
    int IApple.Age { get; set; }

    public Red()
    {
       int quantityRed=2;

       List<Red> red = new List<Red>();
       for (int i = 0; i < quantityRed ; i++) { red.Add(new Red()); }
    }
}

public interface IApple
{
    int Age {get;set;}
}

public class CBasket
{
    private int cycle;
    private List<IApple> content; // чтобы вот тут находились и белые и красные яблоки)

    public void CycleExcute(CBasket iBasket) // Excute my project
    {
        int appleIndex = 0;
        while (appleIndex < iBasket.content.Count) // Проверка яблок в корзине
        {
            IApple nextApple = iBasket.content[appleIndex];
            nextApple.Age++;

            if (nextApple is White)
            {
            //
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Разумеется, можно. `<первый список>.Concat(<второй список>).ToList()`. Но для этого, понятно, нужно иметь сами объединяемые списки. У вас в коде их не видно.

Comment: @VladD , в смысле, нет объединяемых списков ?)
List<White> white = new List<White>(); //1 список
List<Red> red = new List<Red>(); // 2 список
private List<IApple> content; // 3 список "корзина"
Или я не прав?

Comment: Ну, эээ. А вы пробовали сами получить к ним доступ? Вы их создаёте и нигде не сохраняете. Я бы посоветовал прочитать книгу по основам языка всё же.

Comment: этот код надо переписать полностью, при его выполнении можно увидеть название данного сайта :)

Answer (score 3):

Навскидку так может получиться:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int quantity = 2;

            var r = new Red();
            var w = new White();

            for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) 
            { 
                r.red.Add(new Red()); 
                w.white.Add(new White());
            }                

            var b = new CBasket();
            b.AddToBasket(r.red);
            b.AddToBasket(w.white);

            b.CycleExcute();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class White : IApple
    {
        int IApple.Age { get; set; }

        public List<IApple> white = new List<IApple>();
    }

    public class Red : IApple
    {
        int IApple.Age { get; set; }

        public List<IApple> red = new List<IApple>();
    }

    public interface IApple
    {
        int Age { get; set; }
    }

    public class CBasket
    {
        private int cycle;
        private List<IApple> content = new List<IApple>(); // чтобы вот тут находились и белые и красные яблоки)

        public void CycleExcute() // Excute my project
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < content.Count; i++)
            {
                IApple nextApple = content[i];
                nextApple.Age++;

                if (nextApple is White)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("White");
                }
                if (nextApple is Red)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Red");
                }
            }
        }

        public void AddToBasket(List<IApple> newApples)
        {
            content = content.Concat(newApples).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

ПС : никогда в конструкторе класса не стоит создавать еще экземпляр этого же класса.

Comment: Поскольку `List<T>` не ковариантен по `T`, то `List<Red>` не скастится в `List<IApple>`. Я бы поменял тип параметра с `List<IApple>` на `IEnumerable<IApple>`, это решит проблему.

Comment: и правда, об этом я не подумал, спасибо за подсказку !

Comment: Разве нельзя задавать кол-во красных и белых яблок в соответствующих классах? Это делается ток в мэйне ?

Comment: @ВиталийБирюков: Нет, это неправильно с точки зрения проектирования. Яблоко не является списком/набором яблок. Заведите для списка отдельную сущность (класс).

Comment: добавить поле coutn в класс Red можно, а вот заполнить в этом классе список, нет. Это будет как-бы Яблоко, внутри которого целый набор его же самого, это даже на словах звучит дико :)